# Manage Database Connection Pool via Nginx/Haproxy

Tags: nginx, connection-pooling, oracle12c, haproxy

We have multiple instances of a service. Also, we have more than one service sharing a same database.

Currently, we are managing the connection pool in every service instance. 
But, we see some issues as too many idle inactive connections are created and the backend db has limit on too many idle inactive connections.

We are considering at using nginx/haproxy to manage database connection pool.

I looked into haproxy/nginx docs but did not find anything relevant to what I am trying to accomplish.

Has anyone tried implementing a similar solution uisng haproxy/nginx. If so can you please help me on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the haproxy as a tcp load balancer (instead of classical http).

```
frontend incoming
maxconn             25000
mode                tcp
bind                10.0.0.100:3306

default_backend     backend-mysql
```

The loadbalancer has one backend, e.g. backend-mysql. In this backend there are 3 nodes

```
backend backend-mysql
mode                tcp
balance             leastconn
option              httpchk

server              db1 10.0.0.31:3306 check port 9100 inter 12000 rise 3 fall 3 maxconn 256 
server              db2 10.0.0.32:3306 check port 9100 inter 12000 rise 3 fall 3 maxconn 256 backup
server              db3 10.0.0.33:3306 check port 9100 inter 12000 rise 3 fall 3 maxconn 256 disabled
```

You can point your service/clients now to 10.0.0.100. The first db1 is the master db you are using here. The others are a failover. The 2nd node a automated failover (backup). The 3rd server, db3 a manual one (default disabled). Instead, you can change this to a round robin situation (db1-db3), if your database management system is able to serve in master-master mode.

Now you can manage your pools between the clients / haproxy (frontend definition of maxconn). And you can manage the pool between haproxy and the databases (with e.g. maxconn 256/ https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.6.html#3.2-maxconn in the backend section).

To get the failover for the haproxy, you can use vrrp/keepalived. (both share a master IP address. If one server fails, e.g. lb1, the other lb 2 takes over the master ip), https://github.com/acassen/keepalived.